# Must class constructor variables be assigned to private class variables or is there a less code intensive way?

Tags: freepascal

When creating a class you have to assign its parameters to private class variables in order to use those private variables in other procedures and functions in the class. This is code intensive since you have to define the same variable twice.

I have tried using a constructor parameter in a procedure of the same class but it did not work without having to

```
type
    WorldObject=class

    private
        privX, privY, privStartSpriteNum, privEndSpriteNum:word;
        privDirection, privTurn:byte;

    public
        constructor create(x, y, startSpriteNum, endSpriteNum:word; direction, turn:byte);
        procedure draw;

constructor WorldObject.create(x, y, startSpriteNum, endSpriteNum:word; direction, turn:byte);
begin
    privX:=x;
    privY:=y;
    privStartSpriteNum:=startSpriteNum;
    privEndSpriteNum:=endSpriteNum;
    privDirection:=direction;
    privTurn:=turn;
end;

procedure WorldObject.draw;
begin
    writeLn(privX);
    writeLn(WorldObject.x);
end;
```

Was expecting writeLn(WorldObject.x) to print the value of x. 
But got the error: Identifier idents no member "x".

Is there not a way to use the parameter variables from the constructor without having to pass them to private variables?

Thanks!

Comment: No, constructor parameters goes out of scope after the constructor returns. You could have a class variable x though, but that would be independent of any instance. I suggest to pass a record that groups logically related variables together.

Comment: Thanks! I will attempt to do this now.

Comment: Thanks Sertac Akyuz! Passing a record type as parameter to the constructor works perfectly and resolves my issues here, by providing a less code intensive way to program variables and parameters for a Class. I will update my original post with the solution in code.

Comment: I rolled back the edit. We don't put answers in question edits on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be hoping that there is a mechanism where parameters to constructors are automatically stored somewhere, for retrieval later. There is no such mechanism. It is your responsibility to store any state that you need to refer to outside the scope of your constructor. Using fields of your class is the classic method to do this.

Comment: Yeah but that means declaring/defining the exact same variables twice. Seems a bit inefficient. For example, I write the names of parameters in the constructor then write private class variables again for each one then for each one I have to define that the private variable is equal to the parameter, just to be able to use the data I pass to the class in other procedures and functions of that class.

Comment: I'm not responsible for the language. I'm just answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write properties instead of copying private variables, you just need to specify where to read and where to write, since then you can use properties in nested classes or even outside the class.
If you need to use them in the nested classes, declare as protected, if not - as public.

```
property MyProp: TYPE read WriteMyProp read GetMyProp; // for procedure to write and function to read;
property MyPropV: TYPE read MyPropValue write MyPropValue; // for deriving from variable;
```